# Error ball.lua:21: attempt to call global 'checkcollision' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, love2d

Having this problem with my code and i don't get it
basically trying to make a small game as an excercise, but failing when trying the ecollision part

from my beginners knowledge, there is a problem in line 21 (if checkcollision()) inside the "Ball" file, but don't know what thee problem is

[image]

This is my "Ball" code

```
Ball = {}

function Ball:load()
   self.x = love.graphics.getWidth() / 2
   self.y = love.graphics.getHeight() / 2
   self.width = 20
   self.height = 20
   self.speed = 200
   self.xvel = -self.speed
   self.yvel = 0

end

function Ball:update(dt)
    self:move(dt)
    self:collide()
   
end

function Ball:collide()
    if checkcollision(self, Player) then
        self.xvel = self.speed
        local middleBall = self.y + self.height / 2
        local middlePlayer =  Player.y + Player.height / 2
        local CollisionPosition = middleBall - middlePlayer
        self.yvel = CollisionPosition * 5
    end


end

function Ball:move(dt)
    self.x = self.x + self.xvel * dt
    self.y = self.y + self.yvel * dt

end


function Ball:draw()
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
  

end
```

This is my "main" code

```
require("player")
require("ball")

function love.load()
    Player:load()
    Ball:load()

end

function love.update(dt)
    Player:update(dt)
    Ball:update(dt)
end


function love.draw()
    Player:draw()
    Ball:draw()

end

function checkcollision(a, b)
    if a.x + a.width > b.x and a.x < b.x + b.width and a.y + a.height > b.y and a.y < b.height then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end

end
```

My "player" code

```
Player = {}
function Player:load()
    
    self.x = 50
    self.y = love.graphics.getHeight() / 2
    self.width = 25
    self.height = 100
    self.speed = 500

end

function Player:update(dt)
    self:move(dt)
    self:checkbounderies()
    
end

function Player:move(dt)
    if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
        self.y = self.y - self.speed * dt
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
        self.y = self.y + self.speed * dt
    end
end


function Player:checkbounderies()
    if self.y < 0 then
        self.y = 0
    elseif self.y + self.height > love.graphics.getHeight() then
        self.y = love.graphics.getHeight() - self.height
    end
end

function Player:draw()
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

end
```

can someone point me to the right direction

Comment: The code in this question is working fine. Did you mention `checkcollision` in `player.lua` at some point?

Comment: @Luke100000 no, so far, no.. I added my Player code to the question, thanks

Comment: Well, in the end, i went to the main "function checkcollision" and changed the last "a.y < b.height" for "a.y + b,height" and it's working now, i don't know why, but worked

Comment: Maybe you didn't save?

Comment: Well, it was saved, still a misery but it's working now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You require **Ball** code which uses `checkcollision` function as upvalue before defining `checkcollision` function.

Basically you need to define `checkcollision` before using it anywhere; just reorder your imports.

But to solve it the right way, it would be better to move the `checkcollision` function to a separate file:

```lua
-- checkcollision.lua
local function checkcollision(a, b) ....... end
return checkcollision
```

and then require it in any file you want:

```lua
-- Ball.lua

local checkcollision = require "checkcollision"

function Ball:collide()
    if checkcollision(self, Player) then
    .......
```

Comment: I agree with this solution, but in the question the order does not matter as the love callbacks are triggered after (global) `checkcollision` is loaded.

Comment: @Luke100000 you're right. I've missed that out. Thanks!